# ExtentReport is not generated in Selenium testNG

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, extent, extentreports

I have planned to customize the testNG reports. So I have used ExtentReports with the below codes.

Selenium runs properly without any issues but the report is not generated in the specified folder location.

I have added **ExtentReport 2.41.2** maven dependency in my pom.xml file.

Sample Code:

```
public class ExtentA
{
     public static ExtentReports extent;
     public static ExtentTest logger;
     public static WebDriver driver;

     @BeforeSuite
     public void config()
     {
        extent = new ExtentReports("E:/Automation/MyReport.html", true);
        extent.loadConfig(new File("E:/Automation/extentreports-java-2.41.2/extentreports-java-2.41.2/extent-config.xml"));
     }

     @BeforeMethod
     public void beforeMtd(Method method)
     {
        logger = extent.startTest("sample", "test case desc");
        logger.assignAuthor("Mohan");

     }

     @Test
     public void sample()
     {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/selenium/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
        logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Browser Launched successfully");
        System.out.println("Browser launched");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
     }

     @AfterMethod
     public void close()
     {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
        extent.endTest(logger);
     }
}
```

Before running the test case, I have created the html file in loca, but the report is not generated.

Comment: Add `extent.flush();` to the end of your close method.

Comment: It works..!!! Thanks Bill..

Comment: I'm going to post my comment as an answer so that you can mark it as the solution, if you don't mind.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `extent.flush();` to the end of your close method.